# Perché si chiama Babbo Natale?

Tags: word-usage

C'è un motivo per cui si dice Babbo Natale e non Papà o Padre Natale ad esempio?

Secondo [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Babbo%20Natale&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBabbo%20Natale%3B%2Cc0) l'espressione si è diffusa dagli anni '50.

Comment: Sembra che nel 1932 fosse anche ["Papà Natale"](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pap%C3%A0_Natale).

Comment: Magari è un'espressione che è stata usata in qualche pubblicità della Coca Cola. Non dimentichiamoci che è stata colpa sua se ora ci immaginiamo Babbo Natale col vestito rosso ecc.

Comment: Sembra che quest'[articolo di National Geographic](http://www.nationalgeographic.it/popoli-culture/2014/12/24/news/da_san_nicola_a_santa_claus_la_vera_storia_di_babbo_natale-2425592/) sia d'accordo con la ipotesi di @Bakuriu.

Comment: Sembra che i soldati americani dopo la Seconda Guerra Mondiale abbiano anche qualcosa a che vedere.

Comment: @Bakuriu Sembra che sia vittima di una leggenda metropolitana: http://www.snopes.com/holidays/christmas/santa/cocacola.asp

Comment: @Charo …e sembra che anche il _tradottore_ di quell’articolo di NG sia vittima dalla stessa leggenda

Comment: @törzsmókus: Ma l'articolo del National Geographic è completamente d'accordo con l'articolo che tu hai citato!

Comment: @törzsmókus: «Una volta standardizzata (grazie anche alle pubblicità della Coca-Cola, nota del trad. it) la figura di Santa Claus torna in Europa in una sorta di migrazione inversa, adottando nomi come Père Noel, Father Christmas o Babbo Natale e sostituendo un po’ ovunque i vecchi portatori di doni. A diffonderla sono anche i soldati americani sbarcati durante la Seconda mondiale, e l’allegro grassone finisce per simboleggiare la generosità degli USA nella ricostruzione dell’Europa occidentale.»

Comment: @Charo **nota del trad. it.** :P

Comment: @törzsmókus: Non è la Coca-Cola a inventare la figura di Santa Claus, questo lo spiega molto bene l'articolo del NG, ma i soldati americani sbarcati in Europa e anche la pubblicità della Coca-Cola aiutano a diffondere ***in Europa*** un certa immagine del Babbo Natale che si era già standardizzata negli USA come Santa Claus.

Comment: In precedenza a questa diffusione in alcune regioni d'Italia si parlava di San Nicola di Bari e non di "Babbo Natale" (secondo NG).

Comment: Mia nonna lo chiamava Papà Natale

Comment: @törzsmókus - Che significa il tuo commento?

Answer (score 5):

Al liceo, durante le lezioni di storia, studiammo che l'utilizzo di "babbo" piuttosto che "papà" si diffuse soprattutto con il fascismo, a causa della tendenza ad eliminare i termini di origine straniera: se non sbaglio "papà" dovrebbe essere di origine francese (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/papa/). Quindi le trasmissioni radio e la stampa fascista utilizzavano solo il termine "babbo". 
Probabilmente si è utilizzata di più l'espressione "Babbo Natale" anche per questo motivo, e poi è diventata di uso comune.

Comment: So che il fascismo cercò di italianizzare le parole straniere, ma non penso che papà sia una parola di origine francese. In ogni caso 'Babbo Natale' si diffuse dagli anni '50, ben dopo il periodo fascista. Sembra più legato al boom  economico in Italia nel dopoguerra. Grazie comunque per la risposta.

Comment: Per curiosità ho controllato, e ho trovato l'etimologia: pare che venga davvero dal francese. Edito subito la risposta e la aggiungo!

Comment: Secondo l'articolo del National Geographic, l'espressione comincia a diffondersi con i soldati americani sbarcati durante la Seconda Guerra mondiale, dunque questa spiegazione è plausibile.

Answer (score 3):

È vero che "papà" è nato come francesismo per "babbo". *Babbo* era stato incluso già nella prima edizione del Vocabolario degli Accademici della Crusca (1612), mentre la voce *papà* non è stata registata nei dizionari prima del 1825. Ormai è molto divertente leggere la critica dei "gallicismi nella lingua italiana":

> - Pappà e Papà che abbiamo prese ai Francesi, in iscambio delle amorevoli Babbo e Mamma ora com'ora pur troppo in tutta Italia, salvo che in Toscana, sono sulla bocca del ceto signorile (*Lessico della corrotta italianità* di Pietro Fanfani e Costantino Arlìa (1877))
> - Babbo è voce da fanciulli, ed è usata anche dagli adulti a significazione di affetto, e suol dirsi parlando del proprio padre o del padre di colui a cui parliamo. – La voce Papà è una leziosaggine francese che suona nelle bocche di quegli sciocchi, i quali si pensano di mostrarsi più compiti scimmiottando gli stranieri. (*Vocabolario dei sinonimi della lingua italiana* di Pietro Fanfani (1865))

Da quel momento in poi *babbo* pian piano ha perso terreno rispetto a *papà* nella lingua parlata. Ci sono alcune espressioni come *figlio di papà, aspirante papà, neopapà, festa del papà* che non si usano (o sono meno diffuse) con l'alternativa *babbo*. [L'Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/nomi-padre) (citata anche qui sopra) pertanto conclude che, nel caso di Babbo Natale,

> ...In controtendenza è invece il rapporto tra *babbo Natale* e *papà Natale* (11.900.000 a 11.100 occorrenze per le pagine in italiano il 15 dicembre scorso); anzi in alcuni casi, *babbo Natale* è *Il Babbo* per antonomasia... **è più probabile che sia una sorta di specializzazione, un insolito percorso dal nome comune al nome proprio.**